# Пропадает картинка openpyxl

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

Язык python, используется openpyxl

Нужно вписать в шаблон в нужные места данные из базы данных. Person - объект, связанный с базой. Вставка происходит верно, но на выходе пропадает картинка, которая была в исходном файле file.xlsx. Есть ли библиотеки, которые не теряют данные из начальных файлов, картинки например?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
path = 'file.xlsx'
name_out = 'out.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(path)
list = wb.active
list['C8'].value = Person.Surname
list['C9'].value = Person.Firstname
....
list['E28'].value = Person.email
list['E29'].value = Person.INN
list['E31'].value = Person.SNILS
wb.save('/home/olof/Projects/{}.xlsx'.format(name_out))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Внимание:** начиная с `openpyxl 2.5.0` код из вопроса должен отрабатывать правильно - картинки и чарты сохраняются в отредактированом Excel файле.

PS проверено на openpyxl 2.6.0

---

**Ответ от 07.08.2917:**

Насколько мне известно три самых популярных модуля для работы с Excel файлами (`openpyxl`, `xlrd` + `xlwt`, `xlsxwriter`) этого не поддерживают.

`openpyxl`, наверное, самый продвинутый, но и он, по-моему, этого пока не поддерживает. [Вот ответ на похожий вопрос (от 2016-05-13) от автора openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214983/openpyxl-updating-sheet-and-maintaining-graphs-and-images):

> At the moment charts will not be preserved in existing files. You
>   might be able to write your own code to do this.

[И судя по описанию изменений, такая "фича" пока не появилась...](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html)

Comment: Ваш ответ устарел? В новом ответе говорится, что достаточно один пакет поставить.

Comment: @0xdb, перепроверил еще раз для `openpyxl 2.5.0+` код из вопроса работает и без установленного модуля `image`

Answer (score 1):

`pip install image`

у меня без этого пакета не работало с картинками)

Comment: Непонятна связь этого пакета с проблемой из вопроса, в текущем виде ответ не годится

Answer (score 0):

pip install Pillow - мне помогла установка этого пакета